# How retrieve client selection from HTML select tag that is populated with info from database?

Tags: java, html, spark-java, apache-velocity

I've populated a  tag with data from the db with this code:

```
<select name="course">
    <!-- This uses Velocity Template Language. This code loops through -->
    <!-- the map of the query result and populates the list -->
    #foreach($course in $courses)
        <option value="$!{$course.get("coursename")}">$course.get("coursename")</option>
    #end
</select>
```

As you can see, the value of each option is also a variable. I tried the [select name="course"] but that didn't work. This form is handled by this method:

```
//We're using the Sparkjava framework
public static Route addFlashCard = (Request req, Response res) -> {

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();

    String uname = req.session().attribute("currentUser");
    String question = req.queryParams("question");
    String answer = req.queryParams("answer");
    String course = req.queryParams("course");

    boolean result = PreparedQueries.addFlashCard(question, answer, course, uname);

    if(!result)
        model.put("fail", result);
    else
        model.put("success", result);

    return new VelocityTemplateEngine().render(new ModelAndView(model, "html/flashcard.html"));

};
```

I know there isn't an SQL error because none of my try-catch blocks spit out an error. What do I need to do to get the client selection?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, you just want to select the value of that select element (?). If so, I think you mistook in your selector, instead of:

> [select name="course"]

it should be:

> select[name="course"]

Tell me if I misunderstood your question I will edit it